# Power at landside at Budapest airport?

Tags: airports, power, budapest, bud

It seems I will have a few hours to spend at the landside of Budapest airport. There seems to be a cafe Edit: http://www.bud.hu/english/passengers/shopping_and_gastronomy/restaurants/flocafe-8131.html but I can't find information whether it has power outlets. Although I have Priority Pass, all the lounges are airside and the only landside lounge I was able to find is part of a VIP package and as such it has a rather high price http://cavok.co.hu/pdf/pricelist.pdf and is not included in Priority Pass.

Comment: That pdf mentions an airside lounge, doesn't it?

Comment: http://cavok.co.hu/index.php?module=shop&header=4 The Executive Lounge offers immediate, private check-in in the luxury environment of the Terminal 2B landside of Budapest Airport

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having spent time at the cafe mentioned, I can tell you that it indeed does have power outlets and comfortable seating.

However, as it is the prominent cafe at check-in; it gets crowded quickly.

There is often a large line at the counter. If you are traveling with a partner, have one reserve a seat for you.

Answer (score 2):

According to this [sleeping in airports](http://www.sleepinginairports.net/) - [review](http://www.sleepinginairports.net/list.asp?thef=list&s=&act=1&did=8746&region=1&country=Hungary&city=Budapest&terminal=International&pagen=1#.V87LksIrKV4):

> There are armless benches in landside and I have seen several people
>   sleeping there, and fantastic cushioned sofas in the food court
>   between 2A and 2B.  The airport has free WIFI **lots of plugs**.

By "lots of plugs", I read power sockets.

Comment: Maybe Hungary is a bit different and provides the plugs but you have to bring your own outlet (-: